# Why is my Fragment not replacing my Activity layout?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When I pick an item from the `NavigationDrawer` and add a new `Fragment` with a `FragmentTransaction` it doesn't replace the layout of the `Activity` and I cannot figure out why!

This is the layout of my `Activity`:

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    <!-- The main content view -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Location:"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv_disploc"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Temperature:"
        android:id="@+id/tv_disptemp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_disploc"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />


    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        android:onClick="ButtonClick"
        android:id="@+id/btn_search"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_inloc"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_inloc"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_dispsearch"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Search:"
        android:id="@+id/tv_dispsearch"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_outtemp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_outloc"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_disptemp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/et_outloc"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_disploc"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
</FrameLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is the `Fragment` I want to display:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_option"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minWidth="1000dp"
    android:minHeight="1000dp">
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Select your Default Location"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_locations"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: `Fragments` are not supposed to replace the `Activity` layout, they are simply supposed to be a part of it. So it sound like the `Fragment` is doing exactly what it's supposed to do and the only errors are your misconceptions about `Fragments`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Could be. But why then (in order to create DrawerLayout) I have to do it in activity_main.xml ?  Again, I am following steps from Android Developers page on creating Drawer Layout, it could be I dont understand Fragments well.

Comment: You can just as well use a `DrawerLayout` in a `Fragment`

Comment: The general rule is: Put everything the user sees on screen in a `Fragment` except all the stuff that is supposed to be visible across multiple `Fragments` (like for example a `DrawerLayout`). And then use `Activities` to arrange and display those `Fragments`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, will try to fix it

Comment: I would give you more detailed explanations but I am currently on my phone. Maybe later when I have access to my notebook I can write up an answer.

Comment: So for example I should replace `<LinearLayout>` with `<FrameLayout>` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter which layout you are using. `FrameLayouts` are normally used as container for `Fragments` since they are slightly faster and more efficient. Concentrate first on building the layout of the `Fragments` which should contain your user interface for each screen. You can then at runtime display the appropriate `Fragment` through `FragmentTransactions`. The layout of the `Activity` should provide a container element (usually a `FrameLayout` as mentioned above) to display those `Fragments` in.

Comment: Ah, ok! So if I (hopefully) understand correctly, I should inside the `activity_main`, create more `FrameLayout` for each screen that I want to show, giving each one unique ID, so that I can replace them when I need ?

Comment: OR NO! I get it, you meant creating fragments as in creating classes inside my App!

Comment: No, just one `FrameLayout`. Think of it as a placeholder. The Fragments will be displayed inside that `FrameLayout`. For example when the user starts your app you would put the `Fragment` which contains your main menu into the `FrameLayout`. After the user picks an item from the `NavigationDrawer` you would replace the `Fragment` inside the `FrameLayout` with a different one to display some different content to the user.

Comment: Perfect! I think I understsand now, and I'm on it! Hopefully you'll still be around later on, if I encounter some issues. Or if you post an entire Answer, so that I can accept it and up vote it :)

Comment: If you need further help just write a comment here which contains @XaverKapeller. As long as you include that I will get a notification :) just don't forget that you should write a new question if  you are having a new or different problem! You can still post the link to the new question here to notify me!

Comment: Just one more thing: Always include the tag of the programming language you are using in your question (in your case java). Otherwise the automatic syntax highlighting won't work properly! This time I already fixed it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might have a few misconceptions about Activities and Fragments. The general rule is:

> Build your user interface in Fragments (In most cases one `Fragment` equals one
>   screen) and then use Activities to arrange and display those
>   Fragments.

A typical `Activity` layout with `NavigationDrawer` would look like this:

```xml
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <!-- This is the placeholder for your Fragments --> 
    <!-- You can display your Fragments here with FragmentTransactions -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragmentPlaceHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <!-- It would even be better practice to use a Fragment here as well -->
    <!-- But since the Google Tutorials just use a ListView here I will as well -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvDrawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Nothing else besides the placeholder for the Fragments and the necessary parts of the `NavigationDrawer` are supposed to be in that layout. If you would use that layout in an `Activity` in its current state it would essentially display an empty screen besides the `NavigationDrawer` which can be pulled in from the left. Any user interface you build will be added later on through Fragments.

To display a `Fragment` in that layout you have to perform a `FragmentTransaction`. You can add, replace, remove, show or hide multiple `Fragments` in one single `FragmentTransaction`. In the example above you might want to display the `Fragment` which contains your startup screen to the user. To do that you would perform a `FragmentTransaction` like this:

```
// It is best practice to use factory methods to create Fragment instances
final Fragment fragment = StartupFragment.newInstance();

// There are multiple `FragmentManagers`, be sure to always use the right one!
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

// This starts the `FragmentTransaction`.
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

// Now you can define what happens in this transactions
// You can add/replace/remove/hide or show as many Fragments 
// as you want in one `FragmentTransaction`.
// This command specifically adds the Fragment to the placeholder we defined
// in the layout of the Activity
transaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentPlaceHolder, fragment);

// This commits the `FragmentTransaction`.
// Only after you call this will any changes be made
transaction.commit();
```

For brevity the same code as above can also be written as:

```
final Fragment fragment = StartupFragment.newInstance();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.flFragmentPlaceHolder, fragment)
        .commit();
```

The main improvement of writing it like this is that you as a developer can write it **a lot** faster since you can rely on code completion almost the whole time.

If later on the user picks an item from the `NavigationDrawer` then you just have to perform a new `FragmentTransaction` to replace the `StartupFragment` with a different one!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. A nice exaplanation for someone who was not that familiar with Fragments and has issues understanding the developers Guide. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One more thing though: What do you suggest to use in XML failes...LinearLayout or FrameLayout ? Or it doesn't matter which I chose?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. As a placeholder for Fragments one normally uses a `FrameLayout`. Each layout has a very specific use case, for example a `LinearLayout` is used to display multiple `Views` in a horizontal or vertical manner. A `FrameLayout` can be used to overlap multiple Views and a `RelativeLayout` can be used to arrange Views relative to one another (which enables you to build complex layouts very easily). So you see that there is no single answer to this, maybe you could explain what exactly you are talking about and I can give you a better answer.

Comment: I will now create a `fragment_homescreen.xml` that should be replaced onCreate() with the `content_frame` from activity_main.xml . I just like to know how should I define my `fragment_homescreen.xml` .. as RelativeLayout / FrameLayout / LinearLayout ?

Comment: As I explained it really does not matter. You have to pick the layout based on the design of the `Fragment`, for example if you want 10 `Buttons` arranged in a vertical manner, than you can use a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and 10 `Buttons` inside. But you could also use a `RelativeLayout` and arrange each `Button` below another `Button` with the `layout_below` attribute. There are always multiple ways to do this, just don't worry about anything besides designing the layout like you want it to look.

Comment: you were a big help! Great answer! Thanks for everything! :)

Comment: @XaverKapeller : As you Said in your Answer:  If you would use that layout in an Activity in its current state it would essentially display an empty screen besides the NavigationDrawer which can be pulled in from the left. So What will be the solution if my activity layout has button and images. how can I hide it when I replace with fragment?