# Activity layout is still visible after adding fragment to the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is a really lame question, but I really cannot figure out why it happens, so please help me out.

I have a simple **activity** and I add a **fragment** to it **dynamically**. The problem is that once the **fragment** is added to the **activity**, the **activity** layout is also visible. Why does this happen?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            HelloFragment hello = new HelloFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rootView, hello, "HELLO");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    };

    btnLoad.setOnClickListener(listener);
} 
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**HelloFragment.java**

```
public class HelloFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {                       
    /** Inflating the layout for this fragment **/
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_fragment_layout, null);
    return v;
}
}
```

**hello_fragment_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="fragment 1"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image: asfasfsdadgsgsagsag]

[image: After adding fragment]

Comment: Your code seems look perfect to me.

Comment: I know! But why does it now work ?

Comment: @user3282666 Did you found an issue ? I have the same problem

Comment: @Spierki My understanding is that a fragment does not replace the layout of the parent activity. So if you want to work with fragments, it would make sense if you have a bank portion of the activity layout and then add fragments to it.

Answer (score 3):

Convention is to have a FrameLayout that you use fragmentTransaction.replace()/add() on.

You shouldn't have views like TextView and Button in your MainActivity layout file. Instead, have those in another fragment and just have a FrameLayout in your MainActivity xml. Load the fragment with TextView/Button first, and call replace on button click with your new fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Set a background color to your fragment linearLayout and make it clickable

Answer (score 1):

The fragment is just another element on the layout.  Adding it to the layout does not automatically remove other views.  If you want the fragment to replace the content of `rootView` you need to remove `rootview`'s children views first.  Something like:

```
((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootView)).removeAllViews();
```

So your `onClick` method should look like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rootView)).removeAllViews();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        HelloFragment hello = new HelloFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rootView, hello, "HELLO");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Does not work. If I add the transaction to the backstack, and then press the back what I see is an empty layout. I am not yet able to resolve it.

Comment: I think you must implement `onSaveInstanceState` save the activity state, in your case a flag indicating that the fragment is created, then on `onCreate` test the flag and create the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

your rootview work as container for both fragment and your views on activity. check it and make separate view for fragment.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very late to answer this question but for those who are still looking do the following in your activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"/>
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:orientation="vertical">
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And fragment layout to following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="@color/white"    <!--Add this-->
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="OK"/>
</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout 
android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
   View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        HelloFragment hello = new HelloFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, hello, "HELLO");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for this to achieve what you can do is make two fragment one for **textview** and **button** your showing as default when activity is opened and another which you have already created as **HelloFragment**.

From Activity **onCreate()** method call the first fragment with default **textview** and **button** and from the click listener of that button call **HelloFramgent**.

**Step1:** Crate another fragment with any name **MainFragment** having a xml layout as follows:-

**main_fragment_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**MainFragment.java - Class**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {                       
    /** Inflating the layout for this fragment **/
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment_layout, container, false);
    Button btnLoad = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        HelloFragment hello = new HelloFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rootView, hello, "HELLO");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
   };

   btnLoad.setOnClickListener(listener);
   return v;
 }
}
```

**Step2:** Call the **MainFragment** from activity **onCreate()** method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.rootView, mainFragment, "MAIN_FRAGMENT");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Build your user interface in Fragments (In most cases one Fragment equals one screen) and then use Activities to arrange and display those Fragments.
check this: [click here to view detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27185528/5706413)

Answer (score 0):

You have two linear layouts, one inside another, so you need to do the following steps:

1. Set id to 1 linear layout rootView and next to the childview.
2. Find your child view:

   ```
   View view = findViewById(R.id.child_view);

   view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   ```
3. Replace your rootView with your fragment:

   ```
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.rootview, new blankFragment())
       .addToBackStack(null).commit();
   ```
4. Then override:

   ```
   @override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

       if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
           view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }

       super.onBackPressed();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The Activity views are not being masked against the Fragment's views, so both appear. One solution is to load the fragment into a frame in the main activity's layout which has a slight elevation (2 dp). When the fragment is loaded its base elevation will cause it to always draw over the activity. Set the fragments parent container with a color to hide the activity views.

MasterActivity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Activity Title"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:text="Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Button2" />

<!-- Fragment holder, with elevation -->
<FrameLayout
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragHolder"
    />
```

The Fragment layout has a background color:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Test Background Task"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your First Layout invisible while calling fragment and again while returning from fragment make your main view visible and remove fragment at that time so it will not conflict with each other it worked for really well just check it once

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).